# Emoji to JSON encoded, post to web server

Tags: php, ios, iphone, encoding, emoji

Please help me with my problem in posting a JSON decoded emoji character.
I have a UITextView, this text view may have a emoji character. I am posting the data to a web server with the UITextView.text presented as JSON, the problem is when the text has a an emoji, I am not able to get the data. What I do is:

```
$postData = file_get_contents("php://input") to get the data.
```

then I use

```
$post = json_decode($postData,true);
```

to decode the data and have a assoc array and insert the data in database.

here is a code snippet when I insert my data into database.

```
$postData = file_get_contents("php://input");
//$postData = '{"body":"characters here ","subject":"subject here","username":"janus","from_id":"185","to_id":"62"}';
    $post = json_decode($postData,true);
        $data=array(
                'user_id_from'=>mysql_real_escape_string($post['from_id']),
                'user_id_to'=>mysql_real_escape_string($post['to_id']),
                'subject'=>mysql_real_escape_string($post['subject']),
                'message'=>mysql_real_escape_string($post['body']));

                $messages_obj->insert($data);
```

Without an emoji character found, it works fine. no problem. the problem is when an emoji character found, the data in $post (decoded data) is null.

I tried to use dummy data (line 2 in code snippet)

```
//$postData = '{"body":"characters here ","subject":"subject here","username":"janus","from_id":"185","to_id":"62"}';
```

and I succesfully inserted the emoji characters in database. I dont know why but It dont work the same when the data is from the device ($postData = file_get_contents("php://input"))

This is how I encode and post my data in client.

```
    NSMutableDictionary *messageDetails = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[messageDetails setObject:[loginItems objectForKey:@"user_id"] forKey:@"from_id"];
[messageDetails setObject:recipientID forKey:@"to_id"];
[messageDetails setObject:@"subject here" forKey:@"subject"];
[messageDetails setObject:newMessageField.text forKey:@"body"];
    [messageDetails setObject:[loginItems objectForKey:@"username"] forKey:@"username"];


NSString *strPostData = [messageDetails JSONRepresentation];
[messageDetails release];

NSData *postData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[strPostData   UTF8String] length:[strPostData  length]];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Comment: Can i change decode emoji in ios which is encoded in php side ? if yes than how can i do this in both side. i try but no working only both encode and decode same size . Otherwise not working :( so please give me some solution . Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once the data is sent to your php script you need to convert it to a multibyte string:

```
$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8');
```

You can use this function:

```
function cb($content){

  if(!mb_check_encoding($content, 'UTF-8')
   OR !($content === mb_convert_encoding(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8' ), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-32'))) {

    $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8');

  }
  return $content;
}
```

Edit: The data was probably of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded for us and that function converted it correctly.

Comment: Convert it *from what*? `mb_convert_encoding` without a `$from` parameter just takes a guess based on its internal settings from what encoding to convert. It doesn't create "multibyte strings" out of thin air. The data is most likely already in UTF-8, so this is rather pointless. Otherwise if the data is not UTF-8, the fix should be client-side to send the data in the correct encoding to begin with.

Comment: When the data is sent to my PHP script and it is not UTF-8, that's where this function really shines.

Comment: If the data is not UTF-8, what is it then? And why do you not know what it is and can convert accordingly?

Comment: The content type was **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**!!! Sorry i didn't know that at the time, but php/that function automatically converted it correctly to multibyte...

Comment: Can i change decode emoji in ios which is encoded in php side ? if yes than how can i do this in both side. i try but no working only both encode and decode same size . Otherwise not working :( so please give me some solution . Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 1):

emoji characters are most likely transcoded in UNICODE, so it should be sufficient to just send, receive and manage your data in UTF-8.

When receiving with this

```
$postData = file_get_contents("php://input")
```

(I suppose that is a real URL), make sure your php script sends an Content-Encoding header (like the following, choose a MIME-type that suits you)

```
 header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: thanks for the answer :) my php sends an Conten-Encoding header. when I receive data using $postData = file_get_contents("php://input") . I receive the data succesfully but turns out NULL when I use $post = json_decode($postData,true); any idea why it happens? without emoji characters. I can decode the data into json :)

Comment: OK, first check if this happens with other unicode characters (like a random Kanji) as well. If yes, you might have a problem with your client's UTF encoding...

Comment: thanks again :) I tried to use a khanji character and the result is the same. I edited my question. please check if I encoded the data right in my client.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow following steps:

- Convert Emoji characters to base64 and send to server.
- On server side save base64 in database without decode.
- When you want to display Emoji on Application then retrieve same base64 data from server.
- Decode retrieve string and display on app.
- Your Emoji character will display properly.