# Sending emoticons from iPhone to CakePHP but received blank value

Tags: iphone, cakephp, encoding

I am developing an iPhone app that would send emoticons from iPhone to server-side.

But, what the server-side received everytime is always null(or blank?).

I referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194800/emoji-to-json-encoded-post-to-web-server-problem) at SO but with no help.
I also referred HTML_Emoji but it seems to be not an simple encoding or escape character issue.

Is it an issue about carrier's emoticons codes?

So, how could I receive the right emoticons in CakePHP?
Or its not an issue just in CakePHP framework but in PHP or Java or any language else?

What I am developing is the webservice(server-side), and the development of iPhone app is other partner. What sending from iPhone is no problem by theirs saying and with log output(such as \Ud83c\Udfe7) in Xcode when debugging, but I just receive them at server-side with blank value.

By the way, one message sending from our iPhone app with just plain text, it could be received correctly(received by $_POST in CakePHP);
with emoticons in the message, what php received is only plain text without emoticons in it.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you sending them exactly, and how do you determine they are "blank"?! Don't leave out the critical details.

Comment: No, it is not a carrier code issue. How are you sending them from iPhone to CakePHP? Please show us some of your code so we can help.

Comment: What I am developing is the webservice(server-side), and the development of iPhone app is other partner. What sending from iPhone is no problem by theirs saying and with log output(such as _\Ud83c\Udfe7_) in Xcode when debugging, but I just receive them at server-side with blank value. Sorry, I really don't understand you what is the _exactly_ meanings:(, but this is just the case what I encountered. Thanks. By the way, I could receive correct messages without emoctions among it at the server-side.

Comment: Again, how do you determine it's "blank"? What's your code? Do you not receive *anything* server-side? Can you not decode the JSON? Are the emoticons "blank"? What exactly does "what the server-side received everytime is always null" mean? What would you expect instead?

Comment: One message sending from our iPhone app with just plain text, it could be received correctly(received by _$_POST_ in CakePHP); with emoticons in the message, what php received is only plain text without emoticons in it. So I could determine it is _blank_. I don't decode text from json manually as CakePHP do the work for me(and message without emoticons could be received correctly even if it was encoded from iPhone sending). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is send the 'image' file and have php capture that data. In order to do that you need to 'capture' the image data with something like:

```
$img_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

This is PHP specific if you plan on using PHP regardless of the framework. You can read more about how to capture this data here:

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

**UPDATE**

You need to store it as a blob so it will store the image data correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it yesterday but end to useless - the same result as $_POST. :(

Comment: Sorry, everone. It's my fault that I think it could not received at php. In fact, CakePHP could receive it, but the problem is when inserted into MySQL table, the emoticons become blank in table field(varchar). What I inserting into is something like _\Ud83d\Ude04_ which is just a usual smile icon in iPhone. How could I escape it? It is something like json encoding/decoding. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Chuck-Burgess. Sorry, but I think I should open a new topic about DB(MySQL) as the problem is seems to be not the php post receiving.